# How to include another Tab ViewPager in another Fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

So I have successfully implemented a Tab viewpager on a fragment inside the navigation drawer. Now my question is, how do you include another set of tabs in another separate fragment in a single PagerAdapter (Using this pager: you can swipe on any tabs which the tabhost doesnt).

Heres my code for the "other" fragment:

**AttendeesFragment.java:**

```
package com.example.guitarista.citem;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.design.widget.TabLayout;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class AttendeesFragment extends Fragment {

    public AttendeesFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        getActivity().setTitle("Attendees");
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_attendees, container, false);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) v.findViewById(R.id.tab_layout);
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("All"));
        tabLayout.addTab(tabLayout.newTab().setText("VIP"));
        tabLayout.setTabGravity(TabLayout.GRAVITY_FILL); //check gravity center

        final ViewPager viewPager = (ViewPager) v.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        final PagerAdapter adapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager(), tabLayout.getTabCount());
        viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(new TabLayout.TabLayoutOnPageChangeListener(tabLayout));
        tabLayout.setOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                viewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

        return v;
    }

    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater inflater = getActivity().getMenuInflater();
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return  true;
    }

    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return  true;
        }
        return  super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }



}
```

and this is my code for **PagerAdapter.java**

```
package com.example.guitarista.citem;

import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter;

/**
 * Created by smdojt on 1/11/2017.
 */

public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter{
    int mNumOfTabs;
    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, int NumOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNumOfTabs = NumOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position) {
            case 0:
                TabInternationalFragment tab1 = new TabInternationalFragment();
                return tab1;
            case 1:
                TabLocalFragment tab2 = new TabLocalFragment();
                return tab2;
            default:
                return null;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNumOfTabs;
    }
}
```

Notice that there are already tabs in the public fragment (i.e. TabsInternationalFragment, TabsLocalFragment) and now I want to include another tabs on other fragments (i.e. AllTab,VIPTab)

Comment: i don't know your Answer.but before some days i have seen ViewPager with Tablayout Library on Github.Please follow this Link.Hope this will helpfull to you....https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

Comment: and this Link for ChildFragment..
https://github.com/canelmas/AndroidNestedFragments

Comment: I've figured it out. but not with the nested fragments.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a different PagerAdapter this time, and I think this is just a temporary solution.